# TableModel column differentiating between number types

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable used to store numbers. I really only use the table for viewing/sorting. Is there a downfall (other than maybe needed to allocate more space) to giving the columns a class of Double even if some of the columns may have all ints or longs. I can parse the numbers to see if a column contains all of a single type, but that seems like a lot of work if I don't really need to.

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're writing your own `TableModel`, and overriding the `getColumnClass()` method. And furthermore, that you want the table to pick a renderer that right-justifies numbers, but don't otherwise care about rendering differences.

If that's the case, then I'd suggest returning `Number.class`, and not particularly bothering with storing the actual model data as Double.